Same CRS but different location in QGIS
In QGIS I have two files supposed to be located in the same area but they're not overlapping.

The first one is a shapefile of buildings downloaded with projection "CH1903 / LV03" and imported by dragging it in QGIS.
The second file is a list of points imported in QGIS through a CVS file where I chose the projection "CH1903 / LV03".

Despite testing by changing the CRS, both are not aligning. So, does someone know where this issue could come from?
CRS 1:

CRS 2:

Different location:


Your error was to at the steep "a CVS file where I chose the projection "CH1903 / LV03"", you can't choose the projection you need to provide the CRS that match the CSV coordinate (either it was provided along the CSV or you have to identify it by looking at the coordinate)

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is actually a variant of the most common Question here -- If you provide incorrect projection metadata, the GIS  software can't correct the display. Please [Edit] the Question to repair the broken images and give an indication of the correct projection (and values) in the CSV.

Based on the location of the points, they're almost certainly in decimal degrees / latitude-longitude and should be using a geographic coordinate system (GCS). The big question is which GCS?

can you perhaps show a sample of the coordinate values from the CSV file that you are importing?

That issue come very likely from the fact that the coordinates of the points contained in the CSV file are not referred to the "CH1903 / LV03" coordinate reference system.
You need to select the actual coordinate reference system of the coordinates of the points contained in the CSV file when you import such CSV file in QGIS.
